# How do I debug / 'stack trace' the height of an element in html?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

I have an element in a flexbox `flex-direction:column, height:100vh` that is `flex 0 1 100vh` but is overflowing the container. I want to debug it.

I am aware that I can get the height of an element in js using `element.offsetHeight`, but I dont want to use javascript to manually set the height. Instead, I want to trace back exactly why the element is overflowing the container (is it the children?)

How might I do this using devtools? I'm on chrome but will accept firefox if firefox has such capability.

Comment: In any browser devtools, hover on any element (inspect it) and you will get the height. If you also select an element and go to computed you will get the height as well.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of this. As mentioned, I don't want the height however - i want to know WHY the height it is what it is - is it expanding because of the children? Which children? etc.

Comment: Well if you start by debugging like this, you get the height of the parent, you get the height of the child element, if the height of the child element is higher, well then you know where to start to look. The amount of/quality of debug information you have given here it is almost impossible to even start imagining what it looks like. Sorry but unless you give more this is the answer you are stuck with.

Comment: Ok, that problem's gone; i was more asking in general: is there a better way to go about debugging the height of an element than messing with the css and deleting its children one by one until it is at the correct height?

Comment: Bear with me. The point of debugging is to find the source of error, and using devtools let's you do that by inspecting an element, and in your case find the height. If your container has an height that is larger than you set it to be, again your case 100vh, you would have to try find why that is. Do you have any other elements above/below it ect (this is not a question to your specific situation). The browser does what we tell it to do, so it's hard for it to notify us when we think something is wrong. What I'm saying is that it's a part of debugging to try things :)

Comment: Also, again, it is impossible to tell in your specific situation here (I know you solved it, just saying). If you set something to hard values like `height: 20rem;` the element will be that, unless, the parent overrides that. I think for me it's hard to grasp what you mean by correct height? 100vh means different heights in different browsers on different devices. I guess to answer your question in that sense, no there is not.